# bxslider determine swipe event

Tags: jquery, touch, swipe, bxslider

The touch event is enabled for my bxSlider, nou I am trying to get the current slide to call some other functionalities. Works fine on the click event but, I tried to use triggers as 'swipe touch tab' etc but it isn't been triggered.

```
   $("#slider-next, ul li").on("click touch tab swipe", function() {

            countSlides  = slider.getSlideCount()-1;
            currentSlide = slider.getCurrentSlide();
            console.log(countSlides + '/' + currentSlide);

            // Show related flyers
            if (countSlides == currentSlide) {
            alert.log('show');
            $('aside.right').slideUp(350);
            } else {
            alert.log('hide');
            $('aside.right').hide(350); 
            }

    });
```